# Basic Bubble Sort with ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I was implementing a comparator, and it wasn't working, so I thought I'd write a basic bubble sort.

```
int[] numbers = { 5, 8, 14, 1, 5678 };
int tempVar;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
   for(int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++)
   {
            if(numbers[i] > numbers[j + 1])
            {
                   tempVar = numbers [j + 1];
                   numbers [j + 1]= numbers [i];
                   numbers [i] = tempVar;
            }
   }
}
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
     System.out.println(numbers[i].toString());
}
```

Is this tutorial correct at all?
https://blog.udemy.com/bubble-sort-java/

I followed the example and applied it to Last Names in an arraylist, but the results are a bit wack.

```
String a;
String b;
Person c;
Person d;

for (int i=0; i< list.size(); i++){

    for(int j=0; j< list.size()-1; j++){

         a = list.get(i).getLastName();
         b = list.get(j+1).getLastName();
         c = list.get(i);
         d = list.get(j+1);

         if ( a.compareTo(b) < 0 )  {

             Person temp = d;
             list.set(j+1, c);        
             list.set(i, temp); 
         }
     }
 }
```

I'd really like to get a grip on a few methods (like figuring out why my comparator didn't work), but right now I'd just like to get a Bubble Sort to work correctly. Thanks.

Comment: "a bit wack" doesn't give us much to go on... What, exactly, is wack about them?

Comment: The order of the objects in the arraylist are changing, but they are not in alphabetical or any other recognizable order.

Comment: do you want a working comparator ?

Comment: Where are you printing the list and observing this order? Does `getLastName()` always return the same case, or is the first letter sometimes uppercased and sometimes lower?

Comment: @gummiBear Your inner for loop should have initialization as j=i+1 and not j=0 everytime.

Comment: @Sumeet  -wow, that could change a lot. I'm going to try that out now.

Comment: @gummiBear See bubble sort only compares adjacent pairs and yes the tutorial about bubble sort is wrong.

Comment: @Dien  I'll be working on one of those soon. Just trying to get a good grip on this one first. Then I'd like to get a working comparator and also practice doin it with lambdas.

Comment: Replace the `for` in your 2nd code part with my 2nd code part and it will work. @gummiBear

Comment: @SumeetSingh you are wrong.In bubble sort we need to initialize the inner loop with j=0 but we need to limit the upper bound as the larger elements are pushed towards the end

Comment: Yes it is called **bubble sort** because of that, if you sort ascending (i.e. desc) then the big (i.e. small) values rise like bubbles (this means they travel towards the end of the array or list). Look for a visualization of it and you will see. Already +1 @aa1992

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for pointing me in the right direction.
One problem was I forgot to .trim() so compareTo wasn't working and neither was comparing with charAt(0).

Also, I found a better implementation of loops for Bubble-Sort.

This is what now works:

```
    String a;
    String b;
    Person c;
    Person d;

    for (int i= 0; i< list.size() ; i++){

        for(int j=0; j< list.size() - i-1; j++){

             a = list.get(j).getLastName().toUpperCase().trim();
             b = list.get(j+1).getLastName().toUpperCase().trim();

             c = list.get(j);
             d = list.get(j+1);

             if ( a.compareTo(b) > 0)  {

                 Person temp = d;  
                 list.set(j+1, c);
                 list.set(j, temp);

             } 
        }
```

Comment: You don't need to create `temp` (directly put in `d`) other than that it's the combination of aa1992 (looping mechanism) and my answer (the stuff inside the loop). That with the trim was my first comment under my answer ;-) Although you should still take track of changes, at least according to wikipedia when you use this optimized version, so you can break the loop early.

Comment: I agree with @maraca.Also the outer loop can be optimized by setting the upper limit as list.size()-1 instead of list.size().

Answer (score 2):

In Bubble sort you need to compare only the adjacent elements and swap them(depending up on the condition).

If you are doing ascending order than comparing the adjacent elements and swap `if(arr[j]>arr[j+1])`.
This moves the largest elements to the end in the first iteration.Thus there are `n-1` iterations in outer loop to sort the array where n is the length of the array.

Read this  first [Bubble sort](http://geeksquiz.com/bubble-sort/) as the tutorial you mentioned is completely wrong

Corrected code

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length-1; i++)
{
   for(int j = 0; j < numbers.length-i-1; j++)
   {
            if(numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1])
            {
                   tempVar = numbers [j + 1];
                   numbers [j + 1]= numbers [j];
                   numbers [j] = tempVar;
            }
   }
}
```

Here is the [working link](https://ideone.com/674mtx)

Comment: Seriously, I think our two solutions are the only ones working correctly at the moment when making this comment...

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange and inefficient implementation, you compare each number which each other. Something like this is much more intuitive (could be improved a little performance-wise, but that is not the point, you will just save a lot of time not accidently making mistakes with the indices and if you really care about performance and not readability use mergesort or quicksort as Java does [Java is using quicksort for primitive types and mergesort for Objects, probably because for primitive types it doesn't matter if the algorithm is stable or not]):

```
public void bubbleSort(int[] arr) {
    boolean change;
    do {
        change = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
             if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                 int temp = arr[i];
                 arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                 arr[i + 1] = temp;
                 change = true;
             }
        }
    } while (change);
}
```

Applied to your code (sorts ascending):

```
boolean change;
do {
    change = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
         c = list.get(i);
         d = list.get(i + 1);
         a = c.getLastName();
         b = d.getLastName();
         // add special comparison for null values if a or b can be null ("" is ok)
         // toLowerCase() is to compare case-insensitive ('a' != 'A')
         if (a.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.toLowerCase()) > 0) {
             list.set(i, d);        
             list.set(i + 1, c);
             change = true;
         }
     }
} while (change);
```

Sidenote: `s.toUpperCase().compareTo(s.toLowerCase()) == 0` would be `true` if `s` only contains symbols.

Comment: maybe you also want to put a trim in there in addition to the lower case which makes it case insensitive.

Comment: I haven't down voted you,but i think your inner for loop is very inefficient.In bubble sort when you do ascending order,largest element is pushed to the end in first iteration,then the 2nd largest element is pushed to 2nd last position,then the 3rd and this goes till the end.So you do not need to iterate till the end every time as the elements in end are already in its right position.This increases the complexity,suppose there are 100 elements then your loop will iterate total 10000 times where as it should have iterated 4950 times.You can optimize the loop for better performance

Comment: @aa1992 yes, but you are only looking at the worst case, if it is already sorted my algo will  loop 1 time and yours still 4950 times... it depends on the data which one is better.

Comment: Well I mean 100 or 99, not 1, but as I said the point of this implementation is not performance but readability, I wouldn't use bubble sort otherwise. In this case you can use Java's native implementation, but if you want to sort other stuff along then you might have write your own sort.

Comment: I agree.To further optimize my code so that it loops 1 time when array is sorted i can set a boolean variable to false and break if its false after the 2nd loop.

Comment: @aa1992 right, if I also decrease the end then they are the same. I tried to measure the current implementations for random numbers, but it was inconclusive.

Comment: Thought about why the results were inconclusive, here is my explanation: in bubble sort you change values a lot, so this implementation sets change to true many times on the other hand using random numbers quite a few are already in range, so I think for small numbers this would perform better for random numbers and as soon as you reach some threshold aa1992 implementation is better, I guess it is between 100 and 1000 values where this gets continuingly worse.

Comment: In my opinion as its a sorting algorithm so we should always think about the worst cases and try to minimize the complexity for that.As there is no point in  iterating unnecessarily over the elements again and  again which are already sorted.Because if you iterate then you are not gaining the advantage of bubble sort.And as you pointed out that my code is running n times(n being length) when array is already sorted,this can be optimized by using boolean variable as i said.

Comment: Yes, but if you add the boolean then you will also be setting (or checking) it many times when swapping values... btw. quick sort also has worst n^2 and still it is used widely, because it is in-place. My goal was readability, the other was just out of interest, I didn't make the comparison to prove my solution is better at all performance-wise, because it isn't (but could be improved by decreasing the end).

Comment: Actually https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Bubble_sort covers it all including animation. My implementation is bubble sort, aa1992's is optimized bubble sort.

Comment: Yes your solution can be improved of course.I would have added boolean variable at the beginning of inner for and checked at the end of inner for.Ultimately after optimizing(mine and yours) both the code will have same complexity.

Comment: I mean before the inner for and checked after the inner for.

Answer (score 1):

If you write,

```
for(int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++)
```

Then, you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for the following line,

```
tempVar = numbers [j + 1];
```

Because, the array `numbers` has length `5` with last index `4` (as index starts from `0`). So, when `j = 4`, the loop breaking condition `j < numbers.length` or `4 < 5` is `true`, but you will get exception accessing `numbers [4 + 1]` index.

So try

```
for(int j = 0; j < numbers.length -1; j++)
```

or

```
for(int j = i; j < numbers.length -1; j++) // more efficient
```

Now for the second snippet of your code, can you tell me what exactly the *problem* you get?

From a *wild* guess, your `a.compareTo(b) < 0` is not working like what you want.

Note that [compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) returns a value less than 0 if string `a` is [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Lexicographical_order&oldid=659097310) less than the string `b`.

I'm confused what exactly you want, hence produces the following code which may help you to overcome your problem:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sort{
    private static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static ArrayList<String> sortByName(String [] input) {
        String temp;
        for (int i=0; i< input.length; i++){
            for(int j= i; j< input.length-1; j++){
                char first = input[i].charAt(0);
                char sec = input[j +1].charAt(0);
                 if (first < sec)  {
                     temp = input[j +1];
                     input[j +1] = input[i];        
                     input[i] = temp;
                 }
             }
            list.add(input[i]);
         }

        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string[] =  {"Ezen", "Allen" , "Wilker", "Kruden", "Crocket"};
        bubbleSortByName(string);
    }
}
```

Output is a `list` containing:

> list = [Wilker, Kruden, Ezen, Crocket, Allen]

Comment: while true, this is **not an answer** to the question, so it shouldn't have been posted as one.

Comment: It is not THE answer, but is is certainly a valid point and if you are not allowed to comment it is the only way. I see no reason for the downvote. @drewmoore

Comment: @maraca - I agree it's a valid point. Lots of valid points are made every day *as comments*, which is what this should be. (For the record, I would've upvoted it as a comment...)

Comment: @rakebvoid It is efficient `j` starts with `i` instead of `0` like `for(int j = i; j < numbers.length -1; j++).`

Comment: @DrewMoore   I tried compareToIgnoreCase also, but it shouldn't make a difference for the 6 people I'm using as examples in the arraylist.

Comment: @gummiBear, tell me what the two string `a` and `b` contains.

Comment: @rakebvoid  On the second snippet, I'm not getting any errors, the objects just aren't being put in correct order.  I'm not losing any objects or repeating any, just in a random order.

Comment: @rakebvoid    This is my current toString after a sort ..still changing values to see if it helps:   Edward   Ezen   Ezen@live.com   4444   do it!
Alfred    Allen   allen@yahoo.com   434343   notes
Brenda Wilker    Wilka@mailer.com    Wilka@mailer.com    433 565 676    No notes here
Jennifer    Kruden    Jenny@cool.com    555 543 4576    She's really kinda cute.
Davey     Crocket     crocket@here.com     456 968 6754     This is a bunch of text I'm typing.
Jimmy     Dean     iscool@email.com     456 323 4563     This is more text.

Comment: @rakebvoid  FYI  I made a mistake typing Brenda's name and put her whole name in the firstName field, then put her email in the lastName field.

Comment: @maraca, the point of the code is not for input output, the point is how the bubble sort works on string and update a list. The OP is trying to compare by _lasteName_ so i compared in between strings. OP can handle the input output thing.

Comment: @rakeb.void  I upvoted your answer because you pointed out the advantage of using a char for evaluation. I ran some tests and the compareTo function is NOT evaluating as expected.  I ran tests with char and it's fine when I just create a String.  My next problem is it does NOT evaluate correctly when I try to get the char from the String in the list  i.e. list.get(2).getLastName().charAt(0)    I'm not certain why this is.  Also, my chars are not always printing out when I try to print them; is this at all normal in java?  My machine & op system are very current. Same in  Eclipse and Intellij.

Comment: @rakeb.void  This is  not bubble sort.In bubble sort you are suppose to limit the upper bound as larger elements(in case of asc) an smaller elements (in case of desc) are pushed towards the end.Please correct your code.

Comment: @aa1992, You are absolutely right, that's not bubble sort. That is kind of modified proprietary bubble sort which exactly OP wants to overcome his problem. But I should change the class and method name. Ty.

Answer (score 1):

```
Bubble Sort Swap Printer in JAVA:
static void countSwaps(int[] a) {
    int swaps = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<a.length-1; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<a.length-i-1; j++){
            if (a[j] > a[j+1]){
                int temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j+1];
                a[j+1] = temp;
                swaps++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Array is sorted in " + swaps +" swaps.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a small problem with the sort program you used originally.

```
int j=0
```

should be

```
int j=i
```

Also you didn't exactly replace it for string sorting.

```
a.compareTo(b) < 0
```

should be

```
a.compareTo(b) > 0
```

Check this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{
public static void main(String[] args){

   ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
   list.add(new Person("xyz"));
   list.add(new Person("abc"));
   list.add(new Person("pqr"));
   list.add(new Person("lmn"));

   String a;
   String b;
   Person c;
   Person d;
   for (int i=0; i< list.size(); i++){
      for(int j=i; j< list.size()-1; j++){
         a = list.get(i).getLastName();
         b = list.get(j+1).getLastName();
         c = list.get(i);
         d = list.get(j+1);

         if ( a.compareTo(b) > 0 )  {

             Person temp = d;
             list.set(j+1, c);        
             list.set(i, temp); 
        }
     }
  }
  for(Person person: list){
      System.out.println(person.lastName);
  }
}
}
class Person{

   String lastName;
   Person(String str){
      lastName = str;
   }
   public String getLastName(){
      return lastName;
   }
}
```

Comment: I think there is someone who is downvoting all answers in this thread. If you downvote add a comment to explain why.

Comment: Totally agree! Even if it is not correct you could leave a comment first and then downvote if nothing happens.

Comment: just so you know, I haven't downvoted anything -- just still trying to figure it out.

Comment: @gummiBear: :) Have you understood the difference between this and your program? I can explain if you any questions.

Comment: @ Balkrishna Rawoo  I am now at an impasse because I tested compareTo and it doesn't behave as expected.  Also, getting the nameString from the list and doing a .charAt(0) isn't working either as it does on a normal String (don't know why). So I'm at a loss atm as to how to compare them.l

Comment: @gummiBear I made my code case insensitive now, because this seems to be what you want.

Comment: unfortunately this implementation is also increasing start instead of decreasing the end, please correct me if i'm wrong, like @aa1992 did it is correct.

Comment: @maraca  I'm stuck from actually working on the implementation now because I found out the csv reader I'm using to get my contacts from my txt file must be encoding the strings.  Therefore, charAt(0) and compareTo aren't working properly.  I haven't found a way to fix it yet.

Comment: @gummiBear to read the csv file you can just read the text file into a string `s` and then make a `s.split(",")` or if you have whitespaces around the commas `s.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*")`

Comment: @maraca  Thanks Maraca.  Yes, I know implemented with split, but I'm having the same trouble.  I can't access a char by:   System.out.println("char is" +list.get(1).getLastName().charAt(0));   even though a char prints fine when I do:
            char char10 = 'l';
            System.out.println(char10);    I'm not sure why I can access a String this way, but not a char. Even if I set a variable equal to the string from the list (I've done this), I can print the string but not access a char in it with charAt     I have removed the import etc for the csv reader, but still the same problem

Comment: @gummiBear i don't see why you would need to access the char, when you read the file do you have the correct character encoding and conversion to upper lower case depends on default locale (but you can also pass it in as parameter). (pretty sure charAt works fine, try System.out.println("hello".charAt(1)); should print e and the problem is something else like mentioned)

Comment: @maraca Hi maraca.  Yes, I was getting a space from my LastName string in the arraylist.  That part is all fixed now. I tried a new bubble-sort function from a Derek Banas tutorial on youtube ...still not working right the way I have it implemented. I'll look to see if I can submit more code on this question.